# Multvalued Dependencies

Tags: database-theory

Suppose we have the following schema:  `Drinkers(name, addr, phone, beersLiked)`

Also suppose $\text{name} \twoheadrightarrow \text{phone}$. Consider the following tuples:

`Sue a p1 b1`

`Sue a p2 b2`

What other tuples must also be in  `Drinkers` ? Would it be:

`Sue a p2 b1`

`Sue a p1 b2`

Comment: What is the semantic of the arrow? Also, this question appears to be unsuited for this site because questions of the form: "This is the exercise problem, this is my solution. Please grade!" are not interesting for anyone but you. Please see [this related meta discussion](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/597/). If you want to ask a *specific* question about a *specific* part of your attempt, please edit the question accordingly and it may be reopened.